# 389 LDAP server login failed

Tags: linux, centos, ldap

I have followed [this tutorial](https://archyslife.blogspot.com/2018/07/installing-389-ds-on-centos-75_6.html) to set up 389 LDAP server on CentOS 7.8.

```
Computer name [SE1]: ldap.sandbox.domain.eu
Administration Domain [sandbox.domain.eu]:
Suffix [dc=sandbox, dc=domain, dc=eu]:
Directory Manager DN [cn=Directory Manager]:
```

When I try to log in at http://ldap.sandbox.domain.eu:9830/admin-serv/tasks/configuration/HTMLAdmin, it declines my user (I tried "admin" and "cn=Directory Manager"). I found a possible reason that it is caused by hosts/IP addresses allowance. This was in error log:

```
[Wed May 13 09:39:44.633579 2020] [:notice] [pid 6422:tid 139629937064064] Access Host filter is: *.sandbox.domain.eu
[Wed May 13 09:39:44.633605 2020] [:notice] [pid 6422:tid 139629937064064] Access Address filter is: *
[Wed May 13 09:51:49.428058 2020] [:warn] [pid 6422:tid 139629735380736] [client 10.1.1.25:59128] admserv_host_ip_check: Access control based on hostname [*.sandbox.domain.eu] is being used, but the server could not resolve the hostname of client IP address [10.1.1.25].  Either enable HostnameLookups in console.conf (by default it is off for performance reasons), or turn off access control by host/domain name and use access control by IP address only.
```

I found this [manual](https://directory.fedoraproject.org/docs/389ds/howto/howto-adminserverldapmgmt.html#how-to-set-the-hostsip-addresses-allowed-to-access-the-admin-server) with instructions and I decided to make it open to all IP addresses now.

```
ldapmodify -x -D "cn=directory manager" -W
Enter LDAP Password:
dn: dc=sandbox,dc=domain,dc=eu
changetype: modify
replace: nsAdminAccessAddresses
nsAdminAccessAddresses: *
-
replace: nsAdminAccessHosts
nsAdminAccessHosts: *
Ctrl-D to end my input
```

And output:

```
modifying entry "dc=sandbox,dc=domain,dc=eu"
ldap_modify: Object class violation (65)
    additional info: attribute "nsAdminAccessAddresses" not allowed
```

Important finding: my password was accepted here. 
I might enter wrong DN but I have not found what DN is expected here. Any idea?

Then I installed Apache LDAP Studio and I try to connect from my laptop. When I use no authentication, I can browse the LDAP tree. When I enter the credentials, there is an error

[image]

And this is the log:

```
[13/May/2020:13:53:33.090772248 +0200] conn=26 fd=64 slot=64 connection from ::1 to ::1
[13/May/2020:13:53:33.091103269 +0200] conn=26 op=0 BIND dn="cn=directory manager" method=128 version=3
[13/May/2020:13:53:33.091227176 +0200] conn=26 op=0 RESULT err=49 tag=97 nentries=0 etime=0.000423026 - Invalid credentials
[13/May/2020:13:53:33.091320582 +0200] conn=26 op=1 UNBIND
[13/May/2020:13:53:33.091330783 +0200] conn=26 op=1 fd=64 closed - U1
```

The credentials work on server with `ldapmodify`. Where is the problem? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When the manual says:

```
dn: dn of your admin server config entry
```

It's not talking about your database's root entry. It's talking about the entry that holds server configuration (which is somewhere under o=NetscapeRoot), and there is an entire section [about how to find it](https://directory.fedoraproject.org/docs/389ds/howto/howto-adminserverldapmgmt.html#how-to-find-the-admin-server-configuration-entry). In short:

1. Make a search using `(objectclass=nsAdminConfig)` as the filter and `o=netscaperoot` as the search base.
2. Edit the nsAdminAccess attributes on the entry you found in step 1.

Comment: Thank you. I will give a try.

Comment: It found this record:
dn: cn=configuration,cn=admin-serv-ldap,cn=389 Administration Server,cn=Server
  Group,cn=ldap.sandbox.domain.eu,ou=sandbox.domain.eu,o=NetscapeRoot

Comment: I did modified the record as described in the provided document, restarted the server but it had no effect. Even the log is the same. How can I verify that the changes were propagated? The file /etc/dirsrv/admin-serv/local.conf has not been modified and it still holds the  *.sandbox.domain.eu value.